# Page refreshing after fetch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the fetch() method to HTTP POST to a WebApi upon pressing the button on a form.

Why is the page refreshing instead of following up the fetch() call?

This is the start of the form:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.loginClick}>
```

This is the js code:

```
loginClick(event){        
    const url = 'https://localhost:234/users/Login';

    const otherParams = {
        body: this.state.user,
        method: "POST"
    }

    try
    {
        fetch(url, otherParams)
        .then(response => {
            console.log("response after fetch good", response);
            return response.text();
            // Need to check status code.  
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log("data", data)  
            loginSuccessful = true;              
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("after fetch bad", error);
            loginSuccessful = false;       
        });
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        console.log("error", error);
        loginSuccessful = false;
    } 
}
```

I am expecting that the console prints anything there, but it looks like the page is refreshing after fetch(). The http post call does work using Postman with a similar body.

What have I tried so far?

1. Instead of using form onSubmit event handler I tried the onClick handler on the button (Link [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57210240/how-do-i-submit-a-forms-data-to-another-function-without-refreshing-the-page))
2. Somewhere else it was said that calling setState() will cause a refresh, but I am not doing that.

Comment: You need to cancel the default action of the submit: `event.preventDefault();` Off to find the dupetarget...

Comment: oh, it was even another solution in my first link. Thanks!